# Looping list of strings from EF7 Database.SqlQuery

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am wanting to run some tests on a new API we have.  So I want to load about 115 VINs from the db and plug them into the API call.  I know using a model is best practice but just for the sake of testing I would prefer to not have to build a model every time I simply want to test something like this and then have to delete the model and remove it from the context later.

I simply want to get a list of VIN strings which I can loop through somehow.

**Here is my code:**

```
dynamic ret = new ExpandoObject();

ret.vehicles = _context.Database.SqlQuery<string>("SELECT MIN(VIN) FROM bl_DealerInventory WHERE DealerID = "+ dealer.ClientDealerID +" GROUP BY Year, Make, Model, ModelNumber");

for (var i = 0; i < ret.vehicles.Count; i++)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Ran vin "+ ret.vehicles[i]);
}
```

The SQL works but I can't seem to find a way to change it to a list so I can loop through it.  How can I loop through it?  Or do I have to cast it as something else or what?

Here is the Entity framework I am using:

```
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net461" />
```

Let me know if there is any other information needed.  Thank you.

Comment: `_context.Database.SqlQuery("SELECT VIN FROM bl_DealerInventory WHERE DealerID = "+ dealer.ClientDealerID +" GROUP BY Year, Make, Model, ModelNumber").ToList();`?

Comment: That gives an error because it wants SqlQuery to have a type

Comment: And what type is `ret.vehicles`?

Comment: I believe it will be whatever _context.Database.SqlQuery spits out, which is probably like some SqlDbQuery or something.  I ended up solving this issue.  I simply used a foreach instead of a for.  If you put that as the answer I will give it to you.

Comment: Well it's no surprise `foreach` worked, because `SqlQuery` returns `DbRawSqlQuery` which implements `IEnumerable` and executes query when enumerated. I just thought you need to assign result of this query to `ret.vehicles`. Since I didn't came up with answer I can't add it as my own :-)

Comment: @PawełHemperek, *Since I didn't came up with answer I can't add it as my own* This ethic is much appreciated. this would shows *what is community is for and people is not just running behind votes :)

Comment: @Div thanks for the appreciation :-) It's fun to answer questions - to look up things you wouldn't normally look up to and see that people are grateful for your help. It's nice to be recognised with some points, but that's not what SO is all about - at least for me :-)

Answer (score 0):

I got the loop working using a foreach instead of a for loop.

The reason for this as stated by Pawel Hemperek:

Because SqlQuery returns DbRawSqlQuery which implements IEnumerable and executes query when enumerated.